# Maps between manifolds and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading Lee's book about differentiable manifolds, and therein he writes that the rank would be just about the only information to be garnered from the differential that does not depend upon the choice of a basis.

In fact, he seems to mean the correct thing, which is that at both image and domain, a basis may be chosen arbitrarily by changing coördinates according to the post-composition of an affine map whose linear part is a given matrix. This would change the matrix of the differential as
$$
D \mapsto A D B^{-1},
$$
according to the chain rule, where $A$ and $B$ are the linear part of said affine maps. This looks like there is little information about $D$ that one might infer, because one can see to it that the differential becomes a diagonal matrix with $1$s on its diagonal according to its rank.

But suppose now that the manifolds were oriented. Then we could at least inquire whether the sign of the determinant is positive or negative.

Also, if the manifolds were Riemannian, couldn't we restrict attention to normal coördinates? In this case, $A$ and $B$ would be orthonormal matrices, so that not only the precise value of the determinant, but in fact $D D^t$ is preserved, up to an orthogonal change of coördinates. Surely from that one can obtain some information about the map? In fact, shouldn't this be just the volume change brought about by the map, in every direction?

Comment: Can you provide more context? In general one cannot define determinant of linear maps between different vector space. Also, the differential is defined independent of coordinates, so i dont see how uaving a metric would help.

Comment: 1. The first thing you wrote is precisely what I wrote 2. My point was restricting attention to normal coördinates.

Comment: And while the differential is independent of the coördinates, its matrix is not.

Comment: If one defines additional structures on the domain/codomain, then those structures can certainly be used to define all kinds of additional scalars from the differential $d_pf$. In particular, if both are equipped with volume forms, one can define a "volume factor" analogous to the determinant.